# How to send a boolean from a service to a component with observable?(Angular)

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services

How can I send a boolean from a service to a component. This boolean is changing his value inside of 2 functions(onStartBlockUI and onStopBlockUI). For the first function, onStartBlockUI  this boolean is true and for the second function, onStopBlockUI this boolean is false. I want to get this value in a subscription of a component. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingService } from './loading.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loading',
  templateUrl: './loading.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loading.component.scss'],
  providers: [LoadingService]
})
export class LoadingComponent implements OnInit {
  private blockUIState: boolean;
  private subscriptionBlockUI: Subscription;
  constructor(private loadingService: LoadingService) {

    this.subscriptionBlockUI = this.loadingService.onBlockUIState().subscribe(blockUIState => {
      this.blockUIState = blockUIState;
      console.log('this.blockUIState', this.blockUIState);
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptionBlockUI.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BlockUI, NgBlockUI } from 'ng-block-ui';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingService {
  @BlockUI() blockUI: NgBlockUI;
  public blockUIState = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor() {
    this.onStartBlockUI();
    this.onStopBlockUI();
  }
  
  onStartBlockUI(): void {
    this.blockUI.start('Start loading...');
    this.blockUIState.next(true);
  }

  onStopBlockUI(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.blockUI.stop(); // Stop blocking
    }, 2000);
    this.blockUIState.next(false);
  }

  onBlockUIState(){
    return this.blockUIState;
  }
}
```

Comment: your code seems fine to me, what problem do you face running this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use a `BehaviorSubject` instead of a `Subject`.

BehaviorSubjects replay the actual value for each subscriptions and you might miss the first value in your component

Comment: Hi! Can you please check this question? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57954598/how-to-send-a-boolean-from-a-http-request-to-a-componentangular

Answer (score 1):

you need to change it to

```
onStopBlockUI(): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.blockUIState.next(false);
    this.blockUI.stop();  // Stop blocking
  }, 2000);
}
```

Because the inner function of setTimeout() executes after the given time(2000 here).

Comment: Yes, I think this is working with BehaviorSubject. You also deserve mask as best answers but thank you very much!

Comment: Hi! Can you please check this question? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57954598/how-to-send-a-boolean-from-a-http-request-to-a-componentangular